# Plotting a Histogram of Time Values where the x-axis ranges from 17:30 to 7:30

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, histogram, chron

I have made this question a reproducible example. Here is a portion of my data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(`Room Out Date` = c("2018-07-08", "2018-07-08", 
                "2018-07-08", "2018-07-09", "2018-07-09", "2018-07-09", "2018-07-09", 
                "2018-07-09", "2018-07-09", "2018-07-09", "2018-07-09", "2018-07-09", 
                "2018-07-10", "2018-07-10", "2018-07-10"), 
                `Room Out Time` = c("20:11:00", 
                "20:43:00", "22:28:00", "18:00:00", "18:32:00", "18:40:00", "18:59:00", 
                "19:16:00", "19:22:00", "19:38:00", "19:48:00", "21:24:00", "18:12:00", 
                "18:38:00", "18:40:00")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to create a histogram with times on the `x`-axis ranging from `17:30` to `07:30` (with a `binwidth` of `30` minutes) and count on the `y`-axis. I have tried converting the times using the `chron` library as well as with `posixct`, but `ggplot` doesn't seem to like either of those methods. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:** Now collating all dates by half hour period

Try `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(fakedate = ymd("2000-01-01")) %>%  # pretend all happen on same day
  mutate(fakedate_time = as_datetime(paste(fakedate, `Room Out Time`))) %>% 
  mutate(fakedate_time = as_datetime(ifelse(fakedate_time > as_datetime("2000-01-01 12:00:00"),
                                            fakedate_time,
                                            fakedate_time + days(1)))) %>%  # promote some to after midnight
  ggplot(aes(fakedate_time)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1800) +  # bins of 1800 seconds = 30 minutes
  xlim(as_datetime("2000-01-01 17:00:00"), as_datetime("2000-01-02 07:30:00"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. My large dataframe contains days for up to a year of data. I am trying to plot over the time window irrelevant of the day. How would I do this using your method?

Comment: Ah I understand! I've edited code above to try another solution - basically gives every time record a 'fake date' to pretend they all happen on the same day, then adds 1 day to the records taking place after midnight, to give a continuous x axis. Does that produce something more helpful?

Comment: (I've also edited the time slots a little to show how post-midnight times work, try it on your data and see if it sticks at any further errors)

Comment: Hi Andrea, any luck?

Comment: Hi Andrew - Thanks so much for your help! That's perfect and exactly what I needed!